# PyTorch Lightning move tensor to correct device in validation_epoch_end

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I would like to create a new tensor in a `validation_epoch_end` method of a `LightningModule`. From the official [docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/) (page 48) it is stated that we should avoid direct `.cuda()` or `.to(device)` calls:

> There are no .cuda() or .to() calls. . . Lightning does these for you.

and we are encouraged to use `type_as` method to transfer to the correct device.

`new_x = new_x.type_as(x.type())`

However, in a step `validation_epoch_end` I do not have any tensor to copy device from(by `type_as` method) in a clean way.

My question is what should I do if I want to create a new tensor in this method and transfer it to the device where is the model?

The only thing I can think of is to find a tensor in the `outputs` dictionary but it feels kinda messy:

```
avg_loss = torch.stack([x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]).mean()
output = self(self.__test_input.type_as(avg_loss))
```

Is there any clean way to achieve that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

did you check part 3.4 (page 34) in the doc you linked ?

> LightningModules know what device they are on!  construct tensors on the device directly to avoid CPU->Device transfer

```
t = tensor.rand(2, 2).cuda()# bad
(self is lightningModule)t = tensor.rand(2,2, device=self.device)# good
```

I had a similar issue to create tensors this helped me. I hope it will help you too.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I was about to start crying when I read your (working) answer: thanks!

Comment: The documentation changed a bit but the code still works:

device

The device the module is on. Use it to keep your code device agnostic.

`def training_step(self):
    z = torch.rand(2, 3, device=self.device)`

Comment: This answer works in many cases, but for `torch.Tensor([1], device=self.device)` it fails. You can get this error . It works better [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cannot-construct-tensor-directly-on-gpu-in-torch-1-10-1/153751). It is better to use `torch.Tensor([1]).to(self.device)` for these cases